# How to login to phpmyadmin with username and password?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I type `localhost/phpmyadmin` it used to load the page.But now I changed the password from config.inc.php.This is creating a problem now...I am getting this error..
Error

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What is my mistake and how do I overcome.

Thank you,

Comment: Download Navicat, login with navicat and change password of root to blank

Comment: Wrong password, dahh

Comment: did you have password of root??

Comment: No it is not asking password at all??please help

Comment: do you have root access? and what is your OS?

Comment: how to check root access?My Os in XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the mysql root password by logging in to the database directly

> (mysql -h your_host -u root) then run
>
> SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');

Answer (score 0):

Default password of root has been changed,....

Go to: **C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php**
edit

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'insert password here';** insert your root password

Comment: ya I already did that it is not asking me for any password at all

Comment: It did not even ask before

Comment: In Locahost password login to phpMyAdmin is config from file **phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php**